# How to bind dynamic click event to dynamic template ref/var inside *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to dynamically add template reference/variable to file input as well as bind the click event for that button.

I've checked many other stack questions I don't understand since there's no full or proper answer.

So, I decided to put my own question. Please do help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

My code looks like this

```
<div *ngFor="let image of resBgImgProps; let i = index">
   <input (change)="bgImg($event)" type="file" accept="image/*" #??? />
   <button (click)='???.click()'>Select</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dynamic name for the template reference variable; you can use a fixed name. Each iteration of the `ngFor` loop will have it own instance of the variable. Here is how you would use the name `#fileInput`:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of resBgImgProps; let i = index">
   <input #fileInput (change)="bgImg($event)" type="file" accept="image/*" />
   <button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this live demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjyfbg

This is the required code:

```
<div *ngFor="let val of [0, 1, 2]; let i = index">
    <input type="file" id="docFile" name="docFile" (change)="setDocFile()" #docFile>
    <button (click)='docFile.click()'>Select</button>
</div>
```